# Two-column layout without floating elements?

Tags: css, css-float, semantics

How can I position divs side by side without using float? I'm asking because I've read a few times that I shouldn't use float. Or in this particular case is float still the best way to position elements?

Comment: For general layout purposes, floats are the easiest and safest option for creating columns. For data grids and HTML emails, tables are the appropriate way to create columns. Beyond that, it's a matter of what your specific need is in each case.

Answer (score 18):

http://jsfiddle.net/9LaJt/

You should take a look at:

```
display: inline-block
```

As Mark said, to avoid baseline aligment:

```
vertical-align: top
```

Comment: awesome! but look what happens when I add some content http://jsfiddle.net/xvcDT/

Comment: inline elements are always positioned at the bottom of the line. You could set the height manually.

Comment: Inline elements _default_ to baseline vertical positioning. You can set vertical-align: top; http://jsfiddle.net/rFwtv/3/

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options...

- Absolute positioning COL1 width:50% left:0% COL2 width:50% left:50%
- Fixed positioning "same as above but will interfere with scrolling"
- A table layout, even though purists will protest, it will work correctly

Comment: first option seems to work but now I face another problem. the two divs are inside a wrapper div with fixed width and padding. Absolute positioning kills the padding

Comment: @devotchkah - You can add a margin-left and margin-right to the absolute divs that matches the outer wrappers padding.

Comment: yes I believe that would work, but I added padding to the wrapper just so I wouldnt have to add margins or padding to any other div, you know?